# Zingchart getimagedata via coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfchart, zingchart

I'm trying to extract the SVG content of a zingchart generated via CFCHART and pass it to my server to convert the SVG into a PNG

```
$('#downloadGraph').click(function() {
    zingchart.EXPORTURL = 'imageexport.cfm'; 
    zingchart.AJAXEXPORT = true;
    zingchart.exec('myChart', 'getimagedata', {
        format : 'png',
        callback : function(sImageData) {
            console.log(sImageData);

        }
    });
});
```

However I get the following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'zcExec' of null 
cfchart-lite.js:1
zingchart.exec_flash cfchart-lite.js:1
zingchart.exec cfchart-html.js:165
```

I know that the feature works because if you right click on the graph and select 'export to PNG' it works, but i want to put a button on my page to do the same action.

Comment: Where does function zcExec exist and how are you trying to call it?

Comment: it exists in cfchart-lite.js this is the built-in ColdFusion wrapper for zingchart.

Comment: Are you using ColdFusion 10?  Are you using a CFChart format of 'html'?  I found this: [ColdFusion 10 uses ZingCharts as its client side charting engine when you specify ChartType='HTML' and falls back on the older java charting engine for other types](http://blog.davecozens.com/coldfusion-10-now-uses-zingcharts-for-cfchart-sometimes).

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. You can't call [`getImageData`](http://www.zingchart.com/learn/api/api.php) unless the rendering mode is `canvas`. As I'm using 'SVG' it returns -1. However, I think the cfchart-lite.js is not handling this return value properly.

The way is solved this was to use `saveasimage` instead

```
zingchart.EXPORTURL = 'imageexport.cfm'; 
zingchart.AJAXEXPORT = true;

zingchart.exec('datasetChart', 'saveasimage', {
        format : 'png',
        callback : function(sImageData) {
            console.log(sImageData);

    }
});
```

Comment: (Edit) Thanks for posting the answer. So are you using this code in conjunction with a cfchart or did you create your own chart as well? Reason for asking is the api says saveasimage "Only works if exportimageurl is set in zingchart.render." . That property does not seem to accessible from cfchart, from what I can tell.